# WCF Service collection type to Generic List instead of an array

Tags: c#, wcf

I was wondering if there is a way to configure the collection type to Generic List instead of any array on the client end programmatically. I know if we add service reference and go to advanced settings we can specify there. But the way the project is designed is that we have separate assembly for the contracts and is referenced by both the server and the client and also the model types are defined in the same project which are used by both the service and the client. So instead of adding a service reference we are doing everything in the code by defining the bindings and endpoints programmatically. I want to know if this is something that can be achieved in code easily without writing code to convert the arrays into generic lists on the client end.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: how are you code generating?

Comment: we are not doing proxy class generation. All the POCO objects and service contracts are in a separate assembly which are referenced to both the service and the client projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536760/wcf-generic-list-serialized-to-array

Comment: I have looked at that question and the answer states 2 approaches one is updating the reference.svcmap which we will not have as we have not added service references to the client application. Also the other approach suggested using IList instead of the ICollection. The POCOs we have generated are by using the T4 template for EF6 and we will either have to modify the T4 template to change the ICollection to IList. I was looking for a solution on the client end instead of modifying the T4 template. However I will give it a try by manually changing the ICollection to IList and try it first

Comment: changing the ICollection to IList did not help either. I am still getting an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the DataContractSerializer converting the GenericLists to arrays. To handle this issue I had to intercept the deserialization process on the object and convert them back to the lists. I am providing my class definition and the partial class definition to make my answer more easy to understand.

Class Definition:

```
public partial class provider
{
    public provider()
    {
        this.provider_contracts = new HashSet<provider_contracts>();
        this.provider_clinics = new HashSet<provider_clinics>();
        this.provider_custom_field_validations = new HashSet<provider_custom_field_validations>();
        this.provider_directory_languages = new HashSet<provider_directory_languages>();
        this.provider_directory_services = new HashSet<provider_directory_services>();
        this.provider_employees = new HashSet<provider_employees>();
        this.provider_field_exceptions = new HashSet<provider_field_exceptions>();
        this.provider_languages = new HashSet<provider_languages>();
        this.provider_required_fields = new HashSet<provider_required_fields>();
        this.provider_users = new HashSet<provider_users>();
        this.user_privileges = new HashSet<user_privileges>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<provider_contracts> provider_contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_clinics> provider_clinics { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_custom_field_validations> provider_custom_field_validations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_directory_languages> provider_directory_languages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_directory_services> provider_directory_services { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_employees> provider_employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_field_exceptions> provider_field_exceptions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_languages> provider_languages { get; set; }
    public virtual provider_options provider_options { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_required_fields> provider_required_fields { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<provider_users> provider_users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<user_privileges> user_privileges { get; set; }
}
```

My Partial class to handle this issue:

```
public partial class provider
{
    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (provider_contracts != null) provider_contracts = provider_contracts.ToList();
        if (provider_clinics != null) provider_clinics = provider_clinics.ToList();
        if (provider_custom_field_validations != null) provider_custom_field_validations = provider_custom_field_validations.ToList();
        if (provider_directory_languages != null) provider_directory_languages = provider_directory_languages.ToList();
        if (provider_directory_services != null) provider_directory_services = provider_directory_services.ToList();
        if (provider_employees != null) provider_employees = provider_employees.ToList();
        if (provider_field_exceptions != null) provider_field_exceptions = provider_field_exceptions.ToList();
        if (provider_languages != null) provider_languages = provider_languages.ToList();
        if (provider_required_fields != null) provider_required_fields = provider_required_fields.ToList();
        if (provider_users != null) provider_users = provider_users.ToList();
        if (user_privileges != null) user_privileges = user_privileges.ToList();
    }
}
```

Helpful resource: http://yanivh.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/datacontractserializer-and-generic-lists/

I have also answered this question on MSDN forum and am adding a link below 
"http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ccb534c-e310-48d4-8345-160c06568220/collection-types-when-using-channelfactory-without-servicereference?forum=wcf"