# Configure WCF to deserialize arrays as collections without svcutil

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, collections, deserialization, wcf-serialization

I have a `net.tcp` WCF service and its client, each in one assembly and sharing another assembly containing the service interface and DTOs.

The client is implemented as a proxy to the service using a `Channel` instantiated through `ChannelFactory`:

```
public ServiceClient : IService
{
   IService _channel;

   public ServiceClient()
   {
      _channel =  new ChannelFactory<IService>("NetTcp_IService")
         .CreateChannel();
   }

   public DTO ServiceMethod()
   {
       return _channel.ServiceMethod();
   }
}

public class DTO
{
   public IList<int> SomeList;
}
```

As expected, the `SomeList`field of the DTO returned by the client is an array but I would like it to be converted by WCF to a `List`. As you may suspect from the described set-up, **I don't use `svcutil`** (or the *Add Service Reference* dialog for that matter), so [I can't use `configureType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting).

**I don't want to modify the client proxy to instantiate the List** and modify the received DTO in my client proxy because the actual implementation uses a command processor using interfaces resolved through dependency injection at run-time to avoid coupling - and this solution would do the opposite, by requiring the client to perform know service commands.

Therefore, I'm currently using [the work-around which modifies the DTO to internally create the List instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577564/3042204):

```
public class DTO
{
   private IList<int> _someList;
   public IList<int> SomeList
   {
      get { return _someList; }
      set {
         if (value != null)
            _someList = new List<int>(value);
         else
            _someList = new List<int>();
      }
   }
}
```

However, I'd rather avoid this. So the question is:

How can I configure the WCF deserialization so that the `array` is converted to the expected `List`?

Is there any way to configure the deserialization through the binding either in the `App.config` or from code upon `Channel` creation? Maybe through [`ImportOptions.ReferencedCollectionTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.importoptions.referencedcollectiontypes.aspx) or [`CollectionDataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways:

1. Convert data to List in your save methods on Client side
2. Change property type:

   ```
   public IList<int> SomeList;
   ```

   to

   ```
   public List<int> SomeList;
   ```
3. Approach you have shown above (changing type on assigment).
4. [Implement IDataContractSurrogate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/175282d6-c0e0-4d49-9417-efeeb83e0ae1/how-to-force-wcf-service-with-ilist-parameter-to-deserialize-it-as-list-on-server-side-instead?forum=wcf). But you will have to apply a behaviour on client side.

Comment: BTW: Why don't you use IEnumerable? It's more generic interface.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't tried option (2) and it just worked, thanks. I'll also look into (4), which I think is the actual answer. What do you mean by (1), modifying the client proxy or something different? Regarding `IEnumerable`, you are right and I've got no special reason unless I go for your option (2) now.

Comment: You are right, by option 1, I mean modifying your client proxy: 
Impelementing service interface for you Client (as you did - ServiceClient : IService). And in methods SaveSomething(IList<SomeType> lst), convert lst to List: lst.ToList(). But it's not a proper choice for you case.